# Xcode 8 not bolding my text

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to bold my text using the Xcode interface and I've put in all the attributes I would like in the label section of Xcode.

However, only one of the attributes I've selected shows up on the UI View Controller. The bold attribute does not display even when I run the app in the simulator. It just looks like this: [What X code shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3QJA.png)

The color I've selected shows up but it doesn't show the bold text. Now, when I double click on the text within the UI View Controller to edit it, all the attributes I've selected show up like this: [Double Click to edit label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ew9O.png)

I'm not sure if I should just change the bold attribute programmatically or if there is something I'm missing in Xcode and it's just a simple fix.

Please help!

Comment: Are you using a system font or a custom font? Either way: make sure the "bold"-font is available for the Interface Builder

Comment: It is a custom font and I see the bold-font available in the Xcode attribute window under label and it says that it is installed on my computer so I'm guessing it is available.

Comment: And you also linked the font in your Info.plist file?